# polyline on the google map in realtime not working

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to draw polyline in realtime to show users the route they have taken so far. I use google map api, and so far, it shows users' current location with no problem. But polyline doesn't work though (It doesn't draw polyline at all). I call startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges after I check for authorization and draw the polyline inside didupdatelocations. Here's an relevant part of my code :

```
extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedAlways {
           locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
           mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
           mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
           locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    }
}

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = manager.location {
           mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
           path.addCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude,
           longitude: location.coordinate.longitude))
           let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
           polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
           polyline.strokeWidth = 3
           polyline.map = mapView

           locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    }

}
```

**UPDATE-1**

After commenting out stopUpdatingLocation line, it does draw the line. But the line is mangled mess.

**UPDATE-2**

I figured out why the line is a mess instead of one straight line. It's because iphone is changing current location consistently(even though it is stationary), therefore, drawing multiple lines in a small area. How do I stop iphone from doing that?

**UPDATE-3**

I just found out that "Jumpy" current location does not only happen in my app. It also happens in GoogleMap app. So this is probably Iphone/ios GPS issue.

Comment: You just have to remove the noise from the location data.. Basically, Ignore new location values if the new value is only it has a difference of only 0.0001 (something like that)

Comment: Actually, the area is not that really small. It's big enough to get mixed up with user turning to different street to filter them out as noise. I'm using IPhone 5 bty.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to ignore invalid location updates or the updates with low accuracy.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    NSTimeInterval age = -[location.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (age > 120) return;    // ignore old (cached) updates
    if (location.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;   // ignore invalid updates
    if (location.horizontalAccuracy <=10) //you can change 10 to 20 if you want more frequent updates
    {
     // this is a valid update
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.